# Why does TypeScript type inference work when calling a function, but not internally?

Tags: typescript

In the example below TypeScript is able to correctly infer the arguments when calling the `getObjPath` function, but internally it fails on `satisfies ObjPaths`. Can anyone explain this or point me to documentation where I can understand what's happening?

```
const obj = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
} as const;

type Obj = typeof obj;
type ObjKeys = keyof Obj;
type ObjPaths = { [K in ObjKeys]: `${K} | ${Obj[K]}`}[ObjKeys];

const getObjPath = <K extends ObjKeys, V extends Obj[K]>(k: K, v: V) => {
  return `${k} | ${v}` satisfies ObjPaths; // unable to correctly infer
}

getObjPath('a', '2'); // correctly infers
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just the way template literal types work; they don't deal with correlated types like `K` and `Obj[K]`, see [ms/TS#49312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49132).  So you get the equivalent of `\`${ObjKeys} | ${Obj[ObjKeys}\`` instead of the desired type. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Good to know, it does look like that's the same underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

The general issue here is that TypeScript doesn't really have a great way to represent *correlated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types* or [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to such unions. If you have multiple values or expressions that depend on the same union-typed value then the compiler will mistakenly think that each appearance of that expression is independent of the others.  For [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) in particular, this is discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#49132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49132), but the general issue is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

For example, let's see what happens with a value of type `ObjKeys`:

```
function foo(k: ObjKeys) {
  const p = `${k} | ${obj[k]}` as const;
  // const p: "a | 1" | "a | 2" | "b | 1" | "b | 2"; ☹
}
```

Here the type of `p` is inferred by the compiler as `"a | 1" | "a | 2" | "b | 1" | "b | 2"`, as if the types of `k` and `obj[k]` were independent of each other.  It is not actually possible for `p` to be `"a | 2"` or `"b | 1"`, but the compiler thinks it might be, and you'll have trouble if you try to assign it to a variable of type `ObjPaths`.

What you'd like the compiler to have done is more like this:

```
function foo(k: ObjKeys) {
  const q = k === "a" ?
    `${k} | ${obj[k]}` as const :
    `${k} | ${obj[k]}` as const;
  // const q: "a | 1" | "b | 2"
}
```

where each possibility for `k` is considered in turn, and then the results are united together.  This works when you do it manually and redundantly, but not when you write it as one line.  It would be nice to ask the compiler to act *as if* it were doing each case separately, as described in the decline [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051), but it's not possible.

---

So that's the limitation here.  Correlated unions aren't handled very well.  Luckily there is a recommended fix described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where we refactor into a *distributive object type* and generics.  Your code is actually pretty close; all we need to do is make `ObjPaths` generic in the particular key, and make the function return a generic also:

```
type ObjPaths<K extends ObjKeys> =
  { [P in K]: `${P} | ${Obj[P]}` }[K];

const getObjPath = <K extends ObjKeys>(k: K, v: Obj[K]) => {
  return `${k} | ${v}` satisfies ObjPaths<K>; // okay
}
```

(Note that I removed your extra type parameter `V`; unless you actually have different possibilities for `V`, you probably don't want to complicate things by making the function more generic than it needs to be.) Indeed you could annotate the return type as `ObjPaths<K>` and not lose any information you care about:

```
const getObjPath = <K extends ObjKeys>(k: K, v: Obj[K]): ObjPaths<K> => {
  return `${k} | ${v}`; // okay
}
```

And this still behaves as desired from the caller's side:

```
const ok1 = getObjPath('a', '1'); 
// const ok1: "a | 1"
const ok2 = getObjPath('b', '2');
// const ok2: "b | 2"
getObjPath('a', '2'); // error! '2' is not '1'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBDAXDAOQCMRANNjPIUQEwWYC+eEMokUA3JplAJ4AHAKYwA8klQwBIkADM4SHjNETEAaWH82aANZb54pbzkBXMMCgBLcDDkgQACl2E1m7QEoMVDtBiCpAAMAEnRdFgAfGFCERABtXQBdJkDWdnBoHhwAemz0zn9CACJcGCiSIrKYEqq6Sqii+CqKqsbaoq4YQE4yXhxfWABHKV1UFDQSyoB+KhwQsMjo9FiE5NTcNn6YfBmYOfCqmKQVlLT+rJhc-L8B4tLy+uqmqLrmXj4hVSQABVwoAAsIAAedQwYQADygwjAABM2G4tBAAHyoKjoGBxL4wKxgGDqRKEOZfBahNQY1YwJhxPE8TCbADmwigah+-ykwNBEKhsKMGgRiOchHU5BgADdXEc8R5xYgWQDgciUMisDgAE6M0wqnF7YnoEUnCC-KwQORWYRw76-OXqRGdS4gXS4fivXibe0kKQMpkW-6OIi4CjEMgeHiXV26Ei3ZpFWkZWD2ugexnMy2++AB+hEYOYUOxuC6OjFJ4wF6e5M+v3phjBi55YQqlUgFUAQmIDCxbDAIFgpCIvCAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
getObjPath('a', '1'); // correctly infers
getObjPath('b', '2'); // correctly infers
```

But what you've wrote isn't the expected type.

try this :

```
const obj = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2'
} as const;

type Obj = typeof obj;
type ObjKeys = keyof Obj;
type ObjVals = Obj[ObjKeys];
type ObjPaths = { [K in ObjKeys]: `${K} | ${ObjVals}`}[ObjKeys];

const getObjPath = <K extends ObjKeys, V extends ObjVals>(k: K, v: V) => {
  return `${k} | ${v}` satisfies ObjPaths; // unable to correctly infer
};

getObjPath('a', '2'); // correctly infers
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to *reject* `getObjPath('a', '2')`, so this isn't really a solution, unfortunately.